# Merge two data frames - no unique identifier

Tags: r, join, merge

I would like to combine two data frames. One is information for birds banded. The other is information on recovered banded birds. I would like to add the recovery data to the banding data, if the bird was recovered (not all birds were recovered). Unfortunately the full band number is not included in the banding data, only in the recovery data, so there is not a unique column to join them by.

One looks like this:

| GISBLong | GISBLat | B Flyway | B Month | B Year | Band Prefix Plus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -85.41667 | 42.41667 | 8 | 5 | 2001 | 12456 |
| -85.41655 | 36.0833 | 9 | 6 | 2003 | 21548 |

The other looks like this:

| GISBLong | GISBLat | B Flyway | B Month | B Year | Band | R Month | R Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -85.41667 | 42.41667 | 8 | 5 | 2001 | 124565482 | 12 | 2002 |
| -85.41655 | 36.0833 | 9 | 6 | 2003 | 215486256 | 1 | 2004 |

I have tried '''merge''', '''ifelse''', '''dplyr-join''' with no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you try to edit the question, the table appears formatted. And must have done so for OP. But it doesn't show when published.

Comment: Table 2 is already in table 1. what do you need from table 1?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

you should look up `rbind()`. That might do the trick. For it to work the data frames have to have the same columns. I'd suggest you to add missing columns to your first DF with `dplyr::mutate()` and later on eliminate useless rows.

Comment: It's unclear what they're trying to do, but it doesn't seem like they're trying to bind data frames the way you describe. They're probably trying to join them